# Elementary algebra book having proofs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, reference-request

Just wanted to know if there is any **Elementary Algebra** book, which covers proofs of all the basic theorems before getting into exercises.

Like the Theorem, **If a > b > 0, then prove √a > √b.**
and other theorems like that (for equations etc). Or a rigorous book with more emphasis on proofs than exercises.

Comment: I think cengage is a good one for that but it come in parts.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/higheralgebraseq00hall/page/n6 and https://archive.org/details/higheralgebra032813mbp/page/n4

Comment: The example you gave is what you'll find in the first few chapters of many elementary real analysis texts, although I don't understand your distinction between theorems and exercises, because the example you gave is a standard exercise in many elementary real analysis texts and it's a rather specialized result that isn't worth stating as a "theorem" (otherwise, you'd be looking at a cluttered encyclopedia of miscellaneous minor results). More important is being able to prove such a result, and recognizing that it's really just the fact that $f(x) = \sqrt x$ is a strictly increasing function.

Comment: But since you said "elementary algebra", then you'll want to use algebraic manipulative methods, and since square roots are involved, the first thing that occurs to me is to use a rationalization idea: $(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)(\sqrt a + \sqrt b) = a - b,$ and since $\sqrt a + \sqrt b > 0,$ it follows that $\sqrt a - \sqrt b > 0$ if and only if $a - b > 0.$ Thus, $\sqrt a > \sqrt b$ if and only if $a > b.$ In my opinion, the method of proof is the "theorem" you want to learn, and the result itself is the "exercise" you apply the "theorem" to.

Answer (score 2):

Serge Lang - Basic Mathematics might be what you’re looking for.

Comment: Yes, it is good. But it is a mixture of many topics like analytic geometry, trigonometry etc. Just wanted a book which is more focused on algebra only. Like **Edmund Landau' s Foundations of Analysis** does to number systems.